# CSRF token mismatch laravel airlock axios

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, laravel-7, laravel-airlock

- Airlock Version: 1.0.0
- Laravel Version: 7.0.0
- PHP Version: 7.2.0
- Database Driver & Version: MySql 5.7.23

#### Description:

I try login with axios from different domain.
I've the core in "mydomain.com" and the react site in "seconddomain.com".
If I try login from seconddomain.com to mydomain.com with axios API request, it work fine, also without CSRF-COOKIE request.
But If I try to login from my react "localhost:3000" to "mydomain.com", I've "CSRF token mismatch". Why?

This is my configuration:

*in session*

```
'same_site' => "none",
```

*axios configuration*

```
axios.create({
  baseURL: "mydomain.com",
  withCredentials: true,
  responseType: "json",
});
```

*axios login*

```
await API.get('/airlock/csrf-cookie');
response = await API.post(
      '/api/v1/login',
      data
);
```

*cookie from browser - csrf-cooke call*
[image]

*cookie from browser - login call*
[image]

Comment: have you checked the `config\airlock.php` 
 
'stateful' => explode(',', env('AIRLOCK_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'domain here')),

Comment: What domain i must add? "mydomain" (where is the core) or "localhost:3000" (where is react) ?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is `PHP version.`

> for using `laravel-7`  you will need to make sure your server meets
>   the following requirements:
>
> - **PHP >= 7.2.5**
> - BCMath PHP Extension
> - Ctype PHP Extension
> - Fileinfo PHPextension
> - JSON PHP Extension
> - Mbstring PHP Extension
> - OpenSSL PHP Extension
> - PDO PHP Extension
> - Tokenizer PHP Extension
> - XML PHP Extension

check [server-requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#server-requirements) documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by adding `withXSRFToken: true` to `axios.create`.